# Mouse picks up wrong window in W10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, bug

I've had a rather annoying problem where with my dual screen setup and multiple maximised windows. I often drag windows between my screens whilst I'm working. When I have multiple windows maximised on a single screen (all the time), and I drag from the very top of the screen, the mouse often picks up one of the windows underneath the active window. This also happens when I press the close button. It is very annoying and breaks my flow when the wrong window is moved - or worse, the wrong window is closed!

It only happens when the mouse is at the very top of the screen, on the top line of pixels.

I don't know if it is relevant but my laptop screen scaled to 150% and my large screen scaled to 100%.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I can only guess.  First thing, are you using a built in mouse driver or an installed one?  Second thing, have you disabled ALL OF YOUR startup items to see if the problem persists?  It might be a Microsoft bug but probably isn't.

Comment: I am using a Dell USB wired mouse. If plugging it in installs it's own mouse driver, then yes - I have installed one - otherwise no. I have disabled start up items - no resolution to the issue. I reckon it's a Microsoft thing because it doesn't matter what I've got open - it just picks a random window from the 'stack' of maximised windows.

Comment: I would be money that @DanielB is correct in his assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Display scaling, and different scaling factors on multiple displays, are very relevant. So is bad software, which is essentially what this boils down to.

Some applications’ windows simply do not *actually* maximize. This happens mostly with programs that reinvent the wheel and do not have native window frames. Some are pretty good at faking it, too, until they aren’t. VMware Workstation is an example.

Different scaling factors on multiple displays often make this issue worse, because even today, software is *ridiculously* bad at dealing with that.

In the end, there’ll be a visible or invisible area at the edge(s) of the window where clicks go through, to the next actually maximized window below.

**There is no solution to this problem.** Your mouse or its drivers are entirely unrelated.